# Error while using Iterator in struts 2

Tags: java, struts2

I am having an iterator and I am trying to dynamically name the ids

```
 <s:iterator value="roleScreenDetailsList" status ="itemIndex">
     <table>      
    <tr class="normRow" id="row_<s:property value="#itemIndex.count"/>"          style="display:none;">
        <td colspan="8" class="bdr0">
            <s:textfield name="roleDescription" cssClass="txtboxDIS" id="Desc_<s:property value="#itemIndex.count"/>" size="30" disabled="true" />
         </td>

  </table>
 </s:iterator>
```

In the above code , the table row , with class ="normRow" has proper ids generated , but in case of the text field , I am getting the following error

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /WEB-INF/jsp/screens/role.jsp(150,102) Unterminated &lt;s:textfield tag
```

Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<s:iterator value="roleScreenDetailsList" status ="itemIndex">
   <table>
      <tr id="row_${itemIndex.count}">
         <td><s:textfield name="roleDescription" id="Desc_%{#itemIndex.count}" /></td>
      </tr>
   </table>
</s:iterator>
```

- Always use **expression ${}** instead of <**s:property** /> (except for **Type Conversion**), see the **[Performance Tuning](http://struts.apache.org/2.2.1/docs/performance-tuning.html)** of Struts2.
- Always use **[OGNL](http://struts.apache.org/2.2.1/docs/ognl.html)** for attributes of Struts2 tag.

Answer (score 1):

Just try something like

```
 <s:iterator value="roleScreenDetailsList" status ="itemIndex">
     <table>      
    <tr class="normRow" id="row_<s:property value="#itemIndex.count"/>"          style="display:none;">
        <td colspan="8" class="bdr0">
            <s:textfield name="roleDescription" cssClass="txtboxDIS" id='Desc_<s:property value="#itemIndex.count"/>' size="30" disabled="true" />
         </td>

  </table>
 </s:iterator>
```

Comment: It does not work either . I don't get an error.  But I don't get what I require . I get something like Desc_&lts:property value="#itemIndex.count"/&gt as id.

Answer (score 1):

Custom jsp tags are not evaluated inside attributes of other jsp tags. A scriptlet however should work in this case:

```
<s:textfield name="roleDescription" cssClass="txtboxDIS"
    id='Desc_<%= ((org.apache.struts2.views.jsp.IteratorStatus)pageContext.findAttribute("itemIndex")).getCount() %>'
    size="30" disabled="true" />
```